# How do I handle the seek bar using javascript in HTML5 audio tag?

Tags: html, html5-audio

Can anyone help me create a javascript/jquery function to control the HTML5 audio tag control seekbar?? (Or suggest me a web resource from where I can learn).
I want to customize the looks of the default controls and so I want to handle the progress in a different `<div>`. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use any JavaScript slider control that you want and do two things:

- listen for changes (clicks) and set `audioNode.currentTime`
- conversely, periodically set the slider's value to `audioNode.currentTime`

Comment: My problem is, i'm very new to javascript!! :)

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll see what I can do with that. :)

Comment: Hello, can you help me with this?? Is there some event like "onCurrentTimeChange"??
What I want to do is, as the audio plays on, I want to trigger an event and reset the seeker position through something like 

function setSeekerPosition() {
seekbar.value = audio.currentTime;
}

audio.onCurrentTimeChange = setSeekerPosition;

If I'm totally wrong, please redirect me!!

Comment: There is a "timeupdate" event that you can add a function listener to. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/using_audio_and_video_in_firefox